# Using cxml-stp to search HTML

Tags: xml, common-lisp

I'm trying to search HTML using the cxml-stp package, and failing dismally.

```
* (cxml:parse "<html><body><table><tr><td/></tr><tr><td/></tr></table></body></html>" (stp:make-builder))

#.(CXML-STP-IMPL::DOCUMENT
   :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                  #| :PARENT of type DOCUMENT |#
                  :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                 #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                 :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                                #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                                               #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                               :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                                                              #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                                              :LOCAL-NAME "td"))
                                                               :LOCAL-NAME "tr")
                                                            #.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                                               #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                               :CHILDREN '(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT
                                                                              #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |#
                                                                              :LOCAL-NAME "td"))
                                                               :LOCAL-NAME "tr"))
                                                :LOCAL-NAME "table"))
                                 :LOCAL-NAME "body"))
                  :LOCAL-NAME "html")))
* (stp:find-recursively (stp:of-name "td") document)

NIL
* (stp:filter-recursively (stp:of-name "td") document)

NIL
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.  The return value of cxml:parse seems entirely sane, which leads me to believe I'm invoking stp:find-recursively and stp:filter-recursively wrongly.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?  The [docs](http://www.lichteblau.com/cxml-stp/tutorial/pages/7.html) say that this should work:

```
(stp:filter-recursively (stp:of-name "foo") node)
```

FWIW, I'm loading all the packages my app needs through Quicklisp:

```
(ql:quickload '("drakma" "closure-html" "cxml-stp"))
```

Comment: The session you show does not define `document`.

Comment: Wow, you're right; I can't believe I didn't see that ... how embarrassing.  (setq document (cxml:parse ... )) and it works.  I guess my Lisp goggles aren't quite that good yet ...

Comment: Not that this excuses my oversight or anything - but in .NET-land, I'd have expected an ArgumentNullException ... but then, I can see how if this thing is calling itself recursively that it wouldn't be viable to throw an exception given a nil argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
CL-USER> (stp:filter-recursively (stp:of-name "td") (cxml:parse "<html><body><table><tr><td/></tr><tr><td/></tr></table></body></html>" (stp:make-builder)))

(#.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |# :LOCAL-NAME "td")
 #.(CXML-STP:ELEMENT #| :PARENT of type ELEMENT |# :LOCAL-NAME "td"))
```

Comment: Thanks - yeah, as Svante points out above, it helps if you actually assign the return value of the parsing operation to the variable you subsequently search :-)